# Visual Studio launch error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed with Access is denied error

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have recently installed visual studio 2022 on my machine. I am getting this error on startup: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied.
I tried installing 2019 and got the same error. Attaching the below screenshot:
[image: Visual Studio 2022 error]

The activity log is showing me the same thing in detail

```
<entry>
<record>153</record>
<time>2021/12/25 16:16:04.905</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>SetSite failed for package [Visual Studio Common IDE Package]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).&#x000D;&#x000A;System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.PreviewFeatures.UsePreviewSdk.IsPreviewChannel()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.PreviewFeatures.UsePreviewSdk.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.BasePackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__6.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.CommonIDEPackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__20.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass20_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.&lt;JoinAsync&gt;d__76.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)</description>
<guid>{6E87CFAD-6C05-4ADF-9CD7-3B7943875B7C}</guid>
<hr>80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED</hr>
<errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

I tried setting up the permission level of my current local user in my windows 10 OS to full control. But it is not working.
I even followed this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/access-denied-for-visual-studio-common-ide-package/962361) to troubleshoot. Followed the solution there but still no luck.

I know it is not directly related to the visual studio but something is wrong with the permission level set for my machine's local user, the setting of which I haven't changed but still I am not able to find any solution for this.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/access-denied-for-visual-studio-common-ide-package/962361

Comment: @HansPassant, I did follow the same steps as mentioned in the link, i.e.  reset the permissions for that folder to its defaults, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my issue after so much hustle. From the start, it was evident that there was some issue with the permissions given to the user installing the visual studio installer. Although my user was an admin user. Basically, I followed the below steps to get it resolved:

- Run the installer as an administrator(Right-click --> Run as administrator)
- Before this navigate to Program Files --> Microsoft Visual Studio
- Right-click --> properties --> security(make sure administrators have full control)
- Secondly Right-click --> properties --> security --> advanced --> change the owner of the setting to administrator
- Also make sure that replace all child objects checkbox are checked
- Now run the installer as admin.
  This solved the issue for me. Hope this helps others too, facing similar issues.